# how to roll out file every hour with max given files in log4j2

Tags: log4j2, rollover

I want to roll out file on hourly basis and want to keep max 3 file , below are the configuration . But its not executing properly. can anyone help .

```
<RollingFile name="LogFile" fileName="logs/server.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true"
        filePattern="logs/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>&lt;%d{MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a}&gt; &lt;%5p&gt; - %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
                <!--    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5 KB" /> -->
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3" />
</RollingFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention, what exactly is not working. According to you configuration I guess, that you always have a single rolled file. It happens because you did not define a file patter with an index. Add an index into the file pattern:

```
<RollingFile name="LogFile" fileName="logs/server.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true"
    filePattern="logs/server-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log">
    ...
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="3"/>
</RollingFile>
```

Up to three rolled files will be held; files with a higher index will be newer than files with a smaller index.